# How to vertically align both text and image middle of div?

Tags: html, css

It's part of my blog's logo. I have logo image and text inside the div. Now, the image is aligned middle but the text is not in the middle of the div. How can I do this without using margins?
Here's my code:

```html
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  #titleimage {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #titleimage a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  #titleimage img {
    width: 33px;
    height: 36px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  #titleimage span {
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="titleimage">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="images/vk8.png" /><span>PORTFOLIO</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `vertical-align:middle` to your `#titleimage span`

```
#titleimage{
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
#titleimage a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
#titleimage img{
    width: 33px;
    height: 36px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#titleimage span{
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It was really a stupid question :(

Comment: No problem, happy for being able to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `vertical-align` to your `span` tag.

```
 #titleimage span{
        color: white;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 26px;
        vertical-align:middle;/*add this*/
    }
```

Comment: It's so easy :( I didn't even try.

Comment: @VikasKumar It was actually, No problem. Keep on trying.

Answer (score 0):

Add `#titleimage span { vertical-align: middle; }` and remove  `#titleimage img { vertical-align: middle; }`

Comment: damn i'm 38 sec late. Nice fast and good answer :)

Comment: @Relisora Thank you...